Error in pip install pypiwin32 in Dockerfile
I am trying to add python modules in Docker. My Dockerfile looks like:
FROM python:3.9 
ADD ./src ./src

# ADD main.py .
RUN  pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pyyaml
RUN pip install coloredlogs
RUN pip install pypiwin32
# RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32
WORKDIR ./src
CMD ["python", "./main.py"] 

While building the image, I am getting following error:

I tried RUN pip install pywin32 as well, but that also did not work. Thanks.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shot with the actual text of the error message?  Docker images frequently run Linux; is this a Windows-specific Python package?  In typical usage you shouldn't RUN pip install individual packages, but instead use e.g. RUN pip install . to use your pyproject.toml, or extract a requirements.txt lock file and use that for the list of packages to install, so it matches other non-container environments.

@DavidMaze I have already tried via Requirements.txt It did not work, that is why to troubleshoot I was running Pip install individually.
